# Error en un if else a la hora de hacer comparaciones

Tags: java, condiciones, else

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Estoy tratando de hacer un ahorcado, una comparacion de un if y if else la letra de entrada que este en la palabra tendra un valor >=0 y si esta letra no se encuentra tendra valor de -1, al momento de la compracion siempre me marca la opcion del if

```
    System.out.println("Buenos dias a jugar ahorcado");
    System.out.println("Digite la palabra para jugar");
    palabra = entrada.nextLine();[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1]
    
    char ahorcado [] = new char[palabra.length()];

    
    for (int i=0; i<ahorcado.length; i++){
        
        System.out.println("Digite la letra que cree esta en el ahorcado");
        letra = entrada.next().charAt(0);
        System.out.println(palabra.indexOf(letra));
        letrau = letra;

        if (letrau >= 0 ){
            System.out.println("Genial una letra menos");
        }
        else if (letrau == -1 ){
            System.out.println("No es correcta esa letra");
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `letrau` se le está asignando la letra ingresada, por eso nunca será -1.

Eso se soluciona asignando el resultado de la función `indexOf()` a `letrau`.

```
letrau = palabra.indexOf(letra);

System.out.println(letrau);
```